# How to restart multiple server files on npm script using nodemon when changing the files

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, npm-scripts

When I am changing the file on the folder I want to restart the two server files using nodemon in npm script

Here my npm script

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": 
    "nodemon app/api/server.js && nodemon app/backend/server.js"
 },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally done that by using **concurrently** plugin

And my npm start script will be

```
"start": "concurrently \"nodemon app/backend/server.js\" \"nodemon app/api/server.js\" "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *nodemon's configuration file* `nodemon.json` for specifying [additional settings](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files). Place this file at the root of your application.

**nodemon.json**

```
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules/**/node_modules"
  ],
  "verbose": true,
  "watch": [
    "app/api/server.js", //list of files, you want to watch for changes
    "app/backend/server.js" 

    // "app/api/", if you want to watch for all files in sub directory
  ],
  "ext": "js json"
}
```

Making those changes, your `package.json` should look like

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": 
    "nodemon app/api/server.js" // file list was added in nodemon.json
 },
```

Comment: I installed nodemon locally. Is nodemon configuartion file work on locally also?

Comment: yes it will. `nodemon supports local and global configuration files. `  more [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files). but file name needs to be `nodemon.json`

Comment: When i change any file in the backend folder or in the api folder its restarting the server.js file of the api folder, but i also want restart the server.js of the backend folder. watch key will watch only the files which are changing or it points to the restarting server 
files?

Comment: `watch` will allow you to set the list of files, that you want to watch for changes and restart server. Even if you want to watch for changes and restart for backend folder, that's still a file change. isn't? nodemon will handle that as a normal file change and restart backendserver.js. in which case it will be restarted

Comment: One more doubt I have. You're declaring the nodemon.json file, but you didn't mention that anywhere in the package.json file. Is that automatically take the nodemon.json?

Answer (score -1):

here's how your `start` script should look like in the `package.json` file:

```
"start": "nodemon app/api/server.js app/backend/server.js"
```