# watching folder using nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I'm trying to watch changes in my src folder where there would be serveral js files. How can I achieve this? When I run the dev script, I get the console.log from the index file but not from world and hello files. Can anyone explain how can I achieve to get all console.log appears?

directory:

```
folder
 ├── src
 |   ├── hello.js
 |   ├── index.js
 |   └── world.js
 | .gitignore
 | package.json
 | README.md
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --watch src"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14"
  }
}
```

files in src:

```
// index.js
console.log('index.js')
// world.js
console.log('world.js')
// hello.js
console.log('hello.js')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodemon starts a single `.js` file as an entrypoint which would be your `index.js`. If your this file doesn't import the other files to execute the code inside them you will not see the other `console.log`.

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551091/how-to-restart-multiple-server-files-on-npm-script-using-nodemon-when-changing-t) to see how to run nodemon on multiple files side by side.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. I'm looking on the answer you gave me so I could get an overview of it. One question I'm curious, does the main entry point in package.json matters in this case?